# Force sbt to reload whole build definition

Tags: sbt

sbt.version 0.13.15

**Question**:

How can I force sbt to reload and recompile all build definition regardless whether they are changed or not?

**The story**:

I have a multiproject build consiting of multiple sbt and scala files. When I first loaded the project (I am not an author) by `sbt -v` in console I got a list of deprecated warnings (mainly operators like `<<=` `<+=` `<++=`). I want to fix all these but now when I start `sbt -v` again I do not get these warnings any more. Not even after `reload`.

I tried to modify build file (removing import) and reloading then. It showed me errors caused by removed import but no warnings. After fixing import back it showed no warnings still.

Only way I was able to see the list again was to change build file in a way which directly affects build definition and reload it then...

**Bottom line**

So yes I can edit every single sbt file and reload it then. But I wonder there must be a better way. There must be a way how to either force-reload whole build definition or recall that list of warnings somehow.

Thanks for ideas on this!

Answer (score 1):

I found out that compiled build definition is stored in `project/target`. So to achieve what I want it is enough to remove this dir and then reload. It's not a command from sbt but it works.